# azure container registry - manage namespaces and tags users can push to

Tags: azure, docker-registry

I am trying to find out what the Actions for RBAC settings are for azure CLI/Powershell.

1. I can't find a list of Actions/Permissions to assign to a role
2. I don't know what is the right permission to allow a role to only assign to a specific tag, namespace or wildcard..

E.g. company A can only push to a/test and a/service, company B can only push to  b/*

Comment: you wrote what you don't know, but not what you want to. Please formulate questions.

Comment: I already said that.. E.g. company A can only push to a/test and a/service, company B can only push to b/*

I want to configure that my user A can only push to for example only a/test or everything that is tagged with a/ in the name of the docker tag.